# Pandas info not showing all columns and datatypes

Tags: python, pandas, info

I am have imported a csv file onto my Jupyter notebook and trying to obtain all the columns names and datatypes using the info() function. However, I get the following image. Any idea how to resolve it? I can't view all the columns and datatypes, only this vague information

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

use `verbose` as argument to `info`, it gives option to print the full summary. [see full documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html)

You can also use `show_counts` (or `null_counts` for older pandas version since it was deprecated since pandas 1.2.0) argument to see null count information

For pandas >= 1.2.0:
`df.info(verbose=True, show_counts=True)`

For pandas <1.2.0:
`df.info(verbose=True, null_counts=True)`

Comment: The output only shows column name and datatype but doesn't show 'Non-Null Count' Any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: You're the best! Thanks so much!